# Show that there is exactly one positive integer n for which $\sum_{r=1}^n r^3+\sum_{r=1}^n r = 8 \sum_{r=1}^n r^2$

Tags: summation

Can someone show me the working for this? Thanks

AQA A Level Mathematics Further Pure 1 January 2010 Question 8(b)
http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-MFP1-W-QP-JAN10.PDF

And if anyone could explain to me how to type equations properly instead of using text I would really appreciate that, Regards

Comment: The page for LaTeX Markup on StackExchange can be found here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hint:  Write down the standard closed forms for $\sum_1^n r$ and the other two.  Now rewrite your equation using these.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r = \frac{n(n+1)}{2},$$

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6},$$

and

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}.$$

Adding the first two gives us

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3 + \sum_{r=1}^n r = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)(n^2+n+2)}{4}.$$

So then if

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3 + \sum_{r=1}^n r = 8 \sum_{r=1}^n r^2,$$

we have

$$\frac{n(n+1)(n^2+n+2)}{4} = 8\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

Can you see how to proceed?

Comment: I don't see how to proceed

Comment: You have an equation with a variable on both sides. Think of it in terms of algebra. You want to solve for $n$.

Comment: I got ya, thanks